# How to implement 3Sum in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sum

I want to implement a 3Sum and came across the following implementation, why why does it do `0 - num[i]` for sum?

Say the first index has an integer 5 in the array `num`, wouldn't it be `-5` then how can `num[lo] + num[hi]` that will always be positive ever `== sum` when it is negative?

Thank you

```
public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] num) {
    Arrays.sort(num);
    List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length-2; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || (i > 0 && num[i] != num[i-1])) {
            int lo = i+1, hi = num.length-1, sum = 0 - num[i];
            while (lo < hi) {
                if (num[lo] + num[hi] == sum) {
                    res.add(Arrays.asList(num[i], num[lo], num[hi]));
                    while (lo < hi && num[lo] == num[lo+1]) lo++;
                    while (lo < hi && num[hi] == num[hi-1]) hi--;
                    lo++; hi--;
                } else if (num[lo] + num[hi] < sum) lo++;
                else hi--;
           }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: There _is_ one questionable bit in this code, on the line above:  `if (i == 0 || (i > 0 && num[i] != num[i-1]))`.  The `i > 0 &&` is redundant --- `i` is an array's `.length`, so it can never be negative.  The `i == 0` already tests if it's zero (in which case everything after the `||` is skipped), so by the time the `num[i] != num[i-1] is evaluated, `i` _must_ be positive.  The conditional could be rewritten `if (i == 0 || (num[i] != num[i-1])`.  If I were to assign it to a `boolean` variable, I'd name it `isThisANewNumber` or `isThisNumberDifferent`, or maybe `couldProduceNewSolution`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are supposed to find such `A`, `B` and `C` that -

```
A + B + C = 0
```

which can be written as -

```
B + C = 0 - A
```

You're trying to find `num[lo]` and `num[hi]` which along with `num[i]` will sum up to 0. As you have already selected `num[i]`, So you need to make sure other two sum up to `-num[i]`

```
num[i] + (num[lo] + num[hi])
=> num[i] + (-num[i])
=> 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Kaidul do you happen to tutor? Seem like you've always been helpful with algorithms and data structures.

Comment: @LyManeug You're welcome. No I am just a regular guy.. don't find time after a full-time job and other stuffs to do. If you have any further questions on algorithms in future, put the link here in comment section.. I will answer you if I can. Thanks :)

Comment: Great! You've been extremely helpful and was wondering if you can possibly tutor me :D as I'm prepping for an interview. In the meantime, most definitely will post the links here. Thank you in advance!